# É possível criar uma aplicação híbrida com o AngularJS como front, e o java como backend?

Tags: java, angularjs

sou novo no âmbito de programação front, principalmente em AngularJS. Então venho perguntar a vocês se é possível criar um app, seja com ionic ou phonegap, com o angular sendo front-end e o java back-end sem ter nenhuma incompatibilidade ou algo do tipo ?

Comment: Sim, é  possível

Comment: Teria algum material pra me recomendar, algum código, ou alguma palavra chave sobre esse procedimento ? (Talvez não esteja procurando do jeito certo)

Comment: Sim, sua aplicação com o Angular pode ser uma Single Page Application (SPA) que irá consumir uma API (RESTful por exemplo) que pode ser feita em qualquer linguagem server-side, como com o Spring do Java por exemplo.

Comment: Em java você pode procurar por api RESTful como mencionado pelo @LucasCaires, em Angular você procura como consumir essa API, eu faço isso com VueJs e Spring/Kotlin, mas o conceito é exatamente o mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários: sim, é possível.

---

Você pode criar os chamados *Serviços REST* no back-end seja ele qual for (Java, .NET e etc) e consumi-los no front-end seja com qual framework for (Angular, Backbone e etc).

Quando você cria uma *API RESTFul*, você abstrai as tecnologias para um protocolo único de troca de informações, fazendo com que o back-end e o front-end possam trabalhar livremente sem se preocupar com o que o outro está fazendo.